# Get ACF checkbox field choices, outside of the post context

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have ACF checkbox field with three choices. I'm trying to generate filter for post types in my page template. and I need to show the list of all choices from the admin settings. Not only those that were checked for each post type, but all values to generate the filter on the page.
Not getting which exact parameters to use to make this happen. I know how to show posts depending on the checked choices, but I need a list of all values from checkbox field to make the filter with options
[image]

Comment: Use https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/, somewhere in the result of that you should find the field configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's frustrating that it's so hard to find this simple function.

In your case it will be:

```
    $acf_field = acf_get_field('grouping_test'); // returns whole object as an array
    $acf_field['choices']; // returns just choices of the checkbox field
```